# Issue with MS Word mail merge with footnotes

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, csv, footnote

I have kind of a weird issue regarding MS Word's mail merge (MS Word 2010).

I have a simple docx document with some text and some footnotes. Now I am connecting it to a csv file for starting a mail merge.

When hitting "Finish & Merge" --> "Edit individual document", I get exactly what I was expecting, except for an additional blank page at the very end.

I boiled it down to this:
[Document before mail merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIhX1.png)

Which gives me (1 data set in the csv file):
[merged document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqsLe.png)

(Actually using a merge field, does not change the outcome.)

I don't get the blank page, when there are no footnotes present.

How can I suppress the adding of this blank page besides manually delete the made section break?

Comment: Why do you have an end-of-paragraph at the end of the footnote?

Comment: @harrymc It is there by default.

Comment: Just wondering if you can delete it.

Comment: @harrymc It can't be deleted. Furthermore: When I choose "print document" in the "Finish & Merge"-menu, I do not get the extra page. And Word 365 doesn't show this behaviour at all (but I can't use it at work for my problem).

Comment: Can't you print from "Finish & Merge"? I have seen it mentioned as a workaround for this common problem.